# Having trouble with stanford 106B in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode

I am following stanford 106B online and download the assignment file "Mac os x 10.8 files"[here](http://stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1138/assignments/Assignment1-xcode-8.zip). The download gave me proper xcode projects that can be opened with the current version of xcode(5.1.1) I am using.But while trying to run the project I repeatedly get this error. I'm using OS X 10.9.4

clang: error: unknown argument: '-fstack-check' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

is there anyone who can help? I'm trying to fix it for long but failed. it's killing me...

PS: I also found another post asking the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890564/having-trouble-starting-with-stanford-cs106b-course-with-xcode-5-1-1?lq=1

Comment: Try changing the `-fstack-check` argument to `-fsanitize=address`. `stack-check` is for GCC, not Clang.

Comment: I tried. It didn't work anyway. clang: error: unsupported argument 'address' to option 'fsanitize='

Comment: Can you update your version of clang? It could possibly be out of date.